# Is it possible to match ccTTL domains to webRequest listener?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to make firefox addon redirects connection to another link, translating ccTLD domain name to gTLD one. 
(http://foo.bar.co.baz/GETdata)->(http://foo.qux.com/GETdata)

I tried match pattern and other options, without any luck.

- Match pattern (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)
  : It seems like parser does not support ccTLD(ex: foo.co.au), but only gTLD (ex: foo.com).
- events.UrlFilter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/events/UrlFilter)
  : It seems it's not for webRequest.
- `<all_urls>`
  : I also tried to call listener for all domains, then filter it inside the listener by if(details.url.contains("domain-name")) statement, which failed. It did managed to filter other gTLD domains, but not ccTLD ones.

```
var pattern = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/*";

function redirect(requestDetails) {
    console.log("Redirecting: " + requestDetails.url);
    return {
         redirectUrl: "https://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ldbj01lZiP1qe0eclo1_500.gif"
    };
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    redirect,
    {urls:[pattern], types:["image"]},
    ["blocking"]
);

//used MDN example code. permission is given to entire hosts in manifest.json
```

I can't get ccTLD filtered with any options.
It seems internal parser simply can't handle it since 3rd option also failed.
Am I missing something?

Comment: It's either something else wrong in your code (like manifest.json not having the permission for that ccTLD), or maybe the image URL doesn't actually have ccTLD, or maybe it's a bug in Firefox. Especially since `<all_urls>` doesn't work. P.S. The match patterns documentation simply doesn't list all the possible examples, but ccTLD should work just like any other TLD, at least it does in Chrome.